# How to apply xpath in a case insensitive mode in VTD-XML

Tags: java, vtd-xml

I am using VTD-XML and java to parse an XML file using xpath. I need to apply the xpath in a case insensitive mode? Could you please suggest how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Vtd-xml supports lower-case & upper-case functions for Xpath since 2.11
http://vtd-xml.sourceforge.net/faq.html